# What is the maximum voltage gradient between two electrodes?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity, voltage, lightning

What is the maximum voltage gradient between two electrodes?

It would be great if you put the reference to your answer.

**UPDATE**

Our environment is vacuum.

Comment: It depends on the shape of the electrodes and the environment they're in (air, vacuum...) Please supply more details.

Comment: A conventional limit is field emission, which is on the order of MV/m, I believe.

Comment: Hello, well our environment is vacuum. But no condition is there for my question. I do not have info about the shape of electrode. Even A couple of link to the solution would be great and helpful, even if those are general.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general the maximum attainable voltage gradient (=electric field) in a medium is limited by the electrical breakdown voltage/field of the latter. In the case your medium is vacuum, then I reckon your limiting condition would be the breakdown of vacuum. Since electrons/positrons are the lightest known charged particles, one can limit his/her scope with Quantum Electrodynamics. According to Schwinger (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) the maximum electric field $E_S$ before vacuum breakdown would be $E_{S}=|\nabla V|_{max}\approx 10^{18}V/m$.

Comment: The folks who are building accelerators will be happy to hear that... a 7TeV accelerator like LHC could be made the size of a human hair with alien technology like that. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what are limiting conditions when we are speaking about a capacitor with dielectric between its two plates?

Comment: Oh then it can be anything depending on the particular dielectric you are using. Check corresponding wikipedia article for a survey of possible breakdown scenarios: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown . The best understood medium should be gas, here is a detailed explanation of what goes on there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law .